# I want to use superagent in TypeScript-ed React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use superagent in TypeScript-ed React. I try to write [Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) with TypeScript and try to use superagent when reqest server. And I faced errors to use superagent although I can use `marked`.

**When I try to use superagent like marked, request is not found.**

[image]

**When I try to import superagent, other files in same folder are not found.**

[image]

Mmm....

My tsd.d.ts is

```
/// <reference path="react/react.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-dom.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="superagent/superagent.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="marked/marked.d.ts" />
```

package.json is

```
{
  "name": "react-my-first",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

Any help please...

Comment: Have you added tsd.d.ts at the top of your *.tsx files?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but nothing changed... Finally, I solved by removing namespace.. I still don't know why.

Comment: The reason is that you are using ES6 styled modules with the proprietary internal module system of Typescript. They are incompatible.

Answer (score 6):

> When I try to import superagent, other files in same folder are not found.

As soon as you do a module import *your file becomes a module* which is *disconnected from the global namespace* and [*that is a good thing*](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md).

So fix :

```
import * as request from "superagent";
import {CommentList} from "./commentList"; 
// so on
```

Comment: broken link for URL

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Removed 